# Share .JSON file accesible via API key in Wordpress site

Tags: json, wordpress, api

Currently Im building a Wordpress membership site where I would like to offer members data compiled into a .JSON file. An example is: https://mayermultiple.info/current.json

How do I encrypt the json file so only members can acces it e.g. in there own coding environment?

Comment: If you only encrypt it, then it will still be visible to everyone (they just have to decrypt it, which might be hard to do, but.....) So, you should (also) set some access restrictions on those files.

Comment: Yeah exactly. So I’m running a membership plugin which grant new members automatically access to certain parts of the site. But indeed I also want to have generating automatically a key or something which is linked to their membership profile which can be used to access the json file via url.com/file.sjon-key. And can be used than with a GET statement.